# jQuery validation (through '.attr('required', true)') - how to display alert popup if the field is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, alert

I simply validate inputs by running the following code

```
$(".new_address").attr('required', true);
```

This is the general use case when someone wants to validate an input.

Here's my case - I am adding inputs (with `class="new_address"`) to the form. This works well. But now, I need to ensure that user added at least one input with that specific class (`class="new_address"`). How to do that?

If I use only this validation `$(".new_address").attr('required', true);` and trying to send out the form without any inputs with class `new_address`, the form is not sent out, but at the same time - I don't see any error message (because those inputs were not added to the page, so the tiny popups have no space to be displayed.

How to solve this issue? I was thinking of adding the validation rule above merging with alert popup (if this validation doesn't go through, then would be display the alert popup saying that is missing at least on input). But how to combine them?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a javascript each loop for all the inputs with "new_address" class and check if the value is empty or not. If any one value is not empty, trigger the form submit event.

Comment: You should use `$(".new_address").attr('required', 'required');` or `$(".new_address").prop('required', true);`

Answer (score 0):

please try using $.each as below for checking at least one is required

```
$(".new_address").each(function (){
//your code to check least one is required using below attribute
$(this).attr('required', 'required');    
});
```

For alert popup please try using alert in above code. Not able to understand from above mentioned description.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the Html 5 validation, and this is implemented differently for each browser. You can't, to my knowledge, change where and how the notification is displayed for validation errors. And it's not a good choice if your requirement is *"[...] at least one input"*. Adding `required` would make them all required.

What you could do is add your own validation. For example you could attach an event to the click of the submit button that will check if an input exist and/or if it has any value. To check if the element exists you could use `$('.new_address').length`.

A basic example below:

```js
$('#myAdder').click(function() {
  $('#myForm').prepend('<input type="text" class="new_address" value=""/><br/>');
});

$('#mySubmit').click(function() {
  $('#myValidationSummary').text('').hide();
  var oneFilledIn = false;
  $('.new_address').each(function(i, o) {
    if (o.value.length > 0) {
      oneFilledIn = true; //at least one element is filled in
      return false; //exit the each
    }
  });
  if ($('.new_address').length == 0 || !oneFilledIn) {
    $('#myValidationSummary').text('New address must be added and filled in').show();
    return false; //this makes sure the form doesn't post
  }
});

$('#myForm').submit(function() {
  alert('form submitted ok'); //dummy code just to show the form submission
});
```

```css
#myValidationSummary {
  color: red;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 4px;
  display: none;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myValidationSummary"></div>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="button" id="myAdder" value="Add input" />
  <input type="submit" id="mySubmit" value="Submit it" />
</form>
```